# How to simulate periodically clicking a button on a webpage?

Tags: browser, http

I need to go to a webpage, and click a button (called "Generate Daily Trends", as shown in the picture below), and click it again every 1 minute.

Is there any way (e.g., script or code) that I
can automatically "click" the button every minute?
To clarify: I want to *achieve the effect* (on the network and the server)
of clicking the button, as opposed to actually doing something with the mouse.
For example, I should be able to do other things on my workstation
while this is running in the background.

[image]

This needs to be done in a Linux machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a UNIX answer, but if you don't mind leaving it running in the browser:

```js
window.setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementsByName('GENERATE_DAILY_TRENDS')[0].click();
}, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds
```

And if you want a bookmarklet that you can click to get it going (once you're already on the page), add this for the bookmark url:

```js
javascript:(function() {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementsByName('GENERATE_DAILY_TRENDS')[0].click();
    }, 1000);
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use xdotool to get your mouse at your desired position and click the button:

```
xdotool mousemove 100 100 click 1
```

Comment: Can you please see my update>?

Comment: You could use curl or wget and pass the web page you are trying test

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Is this call a http request or what? Can you tell me the terminology that I could look it up (In the past, I have used wget and curl to download file). What terminology that describe my problem? Is it call POST http?

Comment: You could call it a post request method